# Graphql hot chocolate merge data from rest endpoints

Tags: rest, .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I am creating a hot chocolate service as a gateway for merging data from multiple rest endpoints. But I am having a hard time finding any resources that explain how to resolve guids to objects from other endpoints.

For example one service has a db with the products and another service has a db with the reviews.

How do I setup hot chocolate so that this query can be executed?

````
query {
  product(id: $id) {
    id
    title
    review {
      comment
    }
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you had to do is create an `ObjectType` to *resolve* the collection. Something along the lines of...

```
using HotChocolate.Types;

public class ProductResolvers: ObjectType<Product>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Models.Product> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(fld => fld.Reviews)
                  .Resolve(async (context, ct) =>
                  {
                      var prodID = context.Parent<Models.Product>().Id);
                      var ProductReviews= await SomeMethodToGetReviews(prodID);

                      return ProductReviews;
                  });
    }
}
```

Once you have the *resolver*, you will need to register it in your `Startup`

```
services.AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType(q => q.Name("Query"))
        .AddType<ProductsQuery>()
        .AddType<ReviewsQuery>()
        .AddType<ProductResolvers>()  // <=== Register your product resolver class here
```

The great thing with Hot Chocolate is that if you do not specify the `Reviews` in the request, then the Review service will not even be called. Very efficient...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a dataloader and a extended type of the product like so:

```
[ExtendObjectType(typeof(Product))]
public class ProductExtensions
{
public async Task<Review> GetReviewAsync(
    [Parent] Product product,
    ReviewDataLoader dataLoader)
    {
        return await dataloader.LoadAsync(product.Id)
    }
}
```

Then added the extended type like so:

```
services
    .AddGraphQLServer()
    .AddQueryType<Query>()
    .AddTypeExtension<ProductExtensions>()
    .AddDataLoader<ReviewDataLoader>()
```